# How to get the tilt angle of a plane defined by three coordinates in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, coordinates

Given three coordinates (each with x, y and z value), how can I use numpy and/or scipy to calculate the tilt (or inclination) of the resulting plane?

```
a = np.array([32.49, -39.96,-3.86])

b = np.array([31.39, -39.28, -4.66])

c = np.array([31.14, -38.09,-4.49])
```

I want to use this calculations to filter a LiDAR point cloud dataset for roof segments. So the roofs have angles like between 30 and 60 degree.

I know that I would have to rotate the planes defined by the three coordinates to calculate the desired angles but I have no clue how this can be achieved with numpy/scipy.
What I probably need is a rotation like this:

[image]
[image]

UPDATE:

Paul Panzers answer makes it possbible to calculate the planes angles with each axis. But how am I able to rotate the plane so that I get angles comparable on one axis for multiple triplet point sets? My main goal: I want to build triangles of each roof point using the two nearest neighbor points and calculate those angles. If there are like 50% angles between 30 and 60 degreee the roof gets classified as gable for example.

Comment: You need to be more specific: tilt angle with respect to which dimension? In any case you can compute the normal vector of the plane and then project it onto the base vector of the desired dimension in order to determine the angle. Projection is done via the [dot product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Comment: Maybe, you could try to calculate the angle between the normal before tilting and after tilting ?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650904/angle-created-by-tilting-a-plane

Comment: Which kind of rotation do you consider "neutral"? Those around the _z_ axis?

Comment: its not clear which angles you are referring to. Are you referring to the angles in the roof tile itself?

Comment: That's a good question. I think I'm either referring to the angle relative to the x axis or relative to the z axis. Usually the angle of a roof is related the ground plane. I just want something that lets me do comparisons of different roofs with different orientations.

Answer (score 5):

Take the cross product of two differences of your three vectors, for example

```
n = np.cross(b-a, c-a)
```

This will give you a normal vector to your plane. Its angle with any of the coordinate planes will sum to pi/2 with the angle of your plane with the same coordinate plane.

To calculate the angle between the normal vector and a coordinate plane just normalise and take the arc sin of the corresponding component

```
nn = n / np.linalg.norm(n)
angles = np.abs(np.arcsin(nn))
```

Comment: After having some sleep overt this, I don't think this is enough to solve my problem of finding a comparable tilt angle anymore. To my understanding this is giving me the angles that the plane is forming with each axis. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

in general you need to decide on a Axes/Angle convention, several are commonly used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axes_conventions

extracting the "*the tilt angle*" in the OP's wording implies to me finding the angle relative to either the horizon or (local) **Z** (up positive)

but I don't understand Panzer's ans

the cross product for the normal is fine

normalizing the cross product, fine too

the next step however...

the components of `nn`, the normalized cross product vector are the Dot Products with the respective unit basis vectors

finding "angle between" with (normalized input vectors) Dot Products involves the **arccos()**, returning the minimum angle requires allowing for the ordering of the cross product input vectors possibly giving either (upwards/outwards vs downwards/inwards) signed orientation of the normal

I get `angleZ = np.arccos(abs(nn[2]))` for the (assumed upwards/outwards pointing) azimuth angle relative from positve **Z** - a common spherical coordinate system convention that would possibly still need further translation to whatever global or local coordinate system the OP needs, simplest example would be taking the complement `np.pi -  angleZ` to get roof "tilt" relative to the horizontal plane

a 2nd angle is needed to describe the orientation of a plane patch of roof - the angle relative to lat or lon, North, East - and again I think you need to dectect and correct for the possible sign ambiguity of `nn` and use `acrctan2()` for the full signed angle